# Тесты по iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall

Хотел бы для закрепления знаний по iptables пройти тесты. Подскажите какие нибудь ресурсы, где можно пройти онлайн или офлайн тесты по iptables. Ещё интересно тесты по firewalld

Comment: Вопрос "Подскажите ресурсы" - не вполне соответствует тематике сайта.

Comment: например 2ip.ru, portscan.ru/